# Entity Framework Core code first still showing deleted record sqlite

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I'm building a very simple CRUD application to learn C# and EF.
To keep it simple I created 3 domain models, being Player, Tournament, and TournamentEnrollment.

```
public class Player
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";

    public ICollection<TournamentEnrollment> TournamentEnrollments { get; set; }
}

    public class Tournament
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TournamentEnrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}

    public class TournamentEnrollment
{
    [key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public Tournament Tournament { get; set; }
    public Player Player { get; set; }
}
```

For each domain model I also have a DbSet in my DbContext.

Beneath the DAL layer I made a repository for a few basic CRUD operations

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{
    private readonly TmDbContext _context;

    public Repository()
    {
        _context = new TmDbContext();
    }

    public Repository(TmDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    
    public Player ReadPlayer(int id)
    {
        return _context.Players.Find(id);
    }

    public Tournament ReadTournament(int id)
    {
        return _context.Tournaments.Find(id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Tournament> ReadAllTournamentsWithParticipants()
    {
        return _context.Tournaments
            .Include(t => t.Enrollments)
                .ThenInclude(te => te.Player);
    }

    public TournamentEnrollment ReadTournamentEnrollment(int id)
    {
        return _context.TournamentEnrollments.Find(id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TournamentEnrollment> ReadAllTournamentEnrollments()
    {
        return _context.TournamentEnrollments
            .Include(te => te.Player)
            .Include(te => te.Tournament);
    }

    public void DeleteTournamentEnrollment(int id)
    {
        TournamentEnrollment tournamentEnrollment = ReadTournamentEnrollment(id);
        _context.TournamentEnrollments.Remove(tournamentEnrollment);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Beneath I show you my Program.cs from my console application project

```
class Program
{
    private static IRepository _repo = new Repository();
    private static bool _exit;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (!_exit)
        {
            try
            {
                ShowMenu();
                MakeChoice();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void ShowMenu()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1) Show all tournaments");
        Console.WriteLine("2) Remove tournament enrollment");
        Console.WriteLine("3) Show all tournament enrollments");
        Console.WriteLine("0) Exit");
    }

    private static void MakeChoice()
    {
        Console.Write("=>: ");

        if (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int choice))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter a numeric value!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    ShowAllTournaments();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    RemoveTournamentEnrollment();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    ShowAllTournamentEnrollments();
                    break;
                case 0:
                    _exit = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void ShowAllTournaments()
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        IEnumerable<Tournament> allTournaments = _repo.ReadAllTournamentsWithParticipants().ToList();

        foreach (var t in allTournaments)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[{t.Id}] {t.Name}");

            foreach (var te in t.Enrollments)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\t- [{te.Player.Id}] {te.Player.FullName}");
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    private static void ShowAllTournamentEnrollments()
    {
        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (var te in _repo.ReadAllTournamentEnrollments())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[{te.Id}] Tournament = {te.Tournament.Name} | Player = {te.Player.FullName}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    private static void RemoveTournamentEnrollment()
    {
        Console.Write("TournamentEnrollment ID: ");
        int id = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine();

        _repo.DeleteTournamentEnrollment(id);
    }
}
```

Option 1 shows all tournaments with their participants. Now, if I delete a TournamantEnrollment record (using option 2 in the application) and then I ask for all tournaments with their participants (option 1), as expected there is one less participant for a certain tournament.

Now I also have SQLite desktop tool to open the SQLite database file. If I delete a record in the desktop tool (and of course doing a commit) during the console application is running and then press option 1, the deleted record is still showing in the console application. The strange thing is when I press option 3 this record is not showing. So I think it has something to do with the query or caching from EF. I first thought maybe the query for option 1 is only once executed and afterward always in-memory but in the debug I see that there is a query fired so I really don't understand how this is possible.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It's because database query result is consolidated with the cached (tracked) object instances in the context. The "wrong thing" is the usage of static (hence singleton) long lived repository (thus db context). Create new repository(context) for each call, use it to perform the desired operation/query and dispose it afterwards, and the problem is gone. See [The DbContext lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#the-dbcontext-lifetime).

Comment: Thanks for your comment! But why is it that one query (method in repository = ReadAllTournamentsWithParticipants()) is affected but the other one (method in repository = ReadAllTournamentEnrollments()) is not?